# The New Device Access API seems very limited

Tags: nest-device-access

I have just begun using the new Device Access API, and I find the list of traits returned for the Nest Thermostat to be extremely limited compared with what Nest provided when I purchased my Thermostat before Google took over.  The Thermostat belongs to me. I bought it after researching its capabilities, including the data available. I had the expectation that the data that it generates would be available to me.  The list of data values formerly returned is below.

Although there are many values in the list that I never used, I had written personal home automation applications (for my own home) which made use of all the following values formerly returned:

```
$timestamp,
current_version,
current_humidity,
current_temperature,
target_temperature,
target_temperature_high,
target_temperature_low,
target_temperature_type,
hvac_heater_state,
hvac_ac_state,
battery_level,
eco
```

The "eco" value indicated not only manual eco but also auto away.  I could automatically set it home through a trigger that I could set from other apps, in particular, my personal car app when I would be driving home.  Please don't tell me "use the app for that". I had this automated and used it to generate statistical data about the home.

I hope that you will expose -- at a minimum -- all of the above values, and hopefully most, if not all, of the values below.  If necessary, require the device owner to explicitly authorize access to values you have deemed "sensitive" to any particular application.

This is the full list of values formerly returned.  Although I did not use most of them in my applications, some of them were useful when I would make adjustments to my HVAC system, to verify the status of connections.

```
$timestamp,
$version,
alt_heat_delivery,
alt_heat_source,
alt_heat_x2_delivery,
alt_heat_x2_source,
auto_away,
auto_away_enable,
auto_away_learning,
auto_away_reset,
auto_dehum_enabled,
auto_dehum_state,
aux_heat_delivery,
aux_heat_source,
aux_lockout_leaf,
available_locales,
away_temperature_high,
away_temperature_high_adjusted,
away_temperature_high_enabled,
away_temperature_low,
away_temperature_low_adjusted,
away_temperature_low_enabled,
backplate_bsl_info,
backplate_bsl_version,
backplate_model,
backplate_mono_info,
backplate_mono_version,
backplate_serial_number,
backplate_temperature,
battery_level,
can_cool,
can_heat,
capability_level,
click_sound,
compressor_lockout_enabled,
compressor_lockout_leaf,
compressor_lockout_timeout,
cooling_delivery,
cooling_source,
cooling_x2_delivery,
cooling_x2_source,
cooling_x3_delivery,
cooling_x3_source,
country_code,
creation_time,
current_humidity,
current_schedule_mode,
current_temperature,
current_version,
dehumidifier_orientation_selected,
dehumidifier_state,
dehumidifier_type,
demand_charge_icon,
device_locale,
dual_fuel_breakpoint,
dual_fuel_breakpoint_override,
eco,
eco_onboarding_needed,
emer_heat_delivery,
emer_heat_enable,
emer_heat_source,
equipment_type,
error_code,
fan_capabilities,
fan_control_state,
fan_cooling_enabled,
fan_cooling_readiness,
fan_cooling_state,
fan_current_speed,
fan_duty_cycle,
fan_duty_end_time,
fan_duty_start_time,
fan_heat_cool_speed,
fan_mode,
fan_schedule_speed,
fan_timer_duration,
fan_timer_speed,
fan_timer_timeout,
filter_changed_date,
filter_changed_set_date,
filter_reminder_enabled,
filter_reminder_level,
filter_replacement_needed,
filter_replacement_threshold_sec,
filter_runtime_sec,
forced_air,
gear_threshold_high,
gear_threshold_low,
has_air_filter,
has_alt_heat,
has_aux_heat,
has_dehumidifier,
has_dual_fuel,
has_emer_heat,
has_fan,
has_fossil_fuel,
has_heat_pump,
has_hot_water_control,
has_hot_water_temperature,
has_humidifier,
has_x2_alt_heat,
has_x2_cool,
has_x2_heat,
has_x3_cool,
has_x3_heat,
heat_link_connection,
heat_pump_aux_threshold,
heat_pump_aux_threshold_enabled,
heat_pump_comp_threshold,
heat_pump_comp_threshold_enabled,
heat_x2_delivery,
heat_x2_source,
heat_x3_delivery,
heat_x3_source,
heater_delivery,
heater_source,
heatpump_ready,
heatpump_savings,
heatpump_setback_active,
home_away_input,
hot_water_active,
hot_water_away_active,
hot_water_away_enabled,
hot_water_boiling_state,
humidifier_state,
humidifier_type,
humidity_control_lockout_enabled,
humidity_control_lockout_end_time,
humidity_control_lockout_start_time: 0
hvac_ac_state,
hvac_alt_heat_state,
hvac_alt_heat_x2_state,
hvac_aux_heater_state,
hvac_cool_x2_state,
hvac_cool_x3_state,
hvac_emer_heat_state,
hvac_fan_state,
hvac_heat_x2_state,
hvac_heat_x3_state,
hvac_heater_state,
hvac_pins,
hvac_safety_shutoff_active,
hvac_smoke_safety_shutoff_active,
hvac_staging_ignore,
hvac_wires,
is_furnace_shutdown,
is_on_stand,
last_software_update_utc_secs,
leaf,
leaf_away_high,
leaf_away_low,
leaf_schedule_delta,
leaf_threshold_cool,
leaf_threshold_heat,
learning_days_completed_cool,
learning_days_completed_heat,
learning_days_completed_range,
learning_mode,
learning_state,
learning_time,
local_ip,
logging_priority,
lower_safety_temp,
lower_safety_temp_enabled,
mac_address,
maint_band_lower,
maint_band_upper,
max_nighttime_preconditioning_seconds: 18000
model_version,
name,
nlclient_state,
note_codes,
ob_orientation,
ob_persistence,
oob_interview_completed,
oob_startup_completed,
oob_summary_completed,
oob_temp_completed,
oob_test_completed,
oob_where_completed,
oob_wifi_completed,
oob_wires_completed,
pin_c_description,
pin_g_description,
pin_ob_description,
pin_rc_description,
pin_rh_description,
pin_star_description,
pin_w1_description,
pin_w2aux_description,
pin_y1_description,
pin_y2_description,
postal_code,
preconditioning_active,
preconditioning_enabled,
preconditioning_ready,
pro_id,
radiant_control_enabled,
range_enable,
rcs_capable,
rssi,
safety_state,
safety_state_time,
safety_temp_activating_hvac,
schedule_learning_reset,
schedules,
serial_number,
should_wake_on_approach,
smoke_shutoff_supported,
star_type,
sunlight_correction_active,
sunlight_correction_enabled,
sunlight_correction_ready,
switch_system_off,
target_change_pending,
target_humidity,
target_humidity_enabled,
target_temperature,
target_temperature_high,
target_temperature_low,
target_temperature_type,
target_time_confidence,
temperature_lock,
temperature_lock_high_temp,
temperature_lock_low_temp,
temperature_lock_pin_hash,
temperature_scale,
time_to_target,
time_to_target_training,
tou_icon,
touched_by,
type,
upper_safety_temp,
upper_safety_temp_enabled,
user_brightness,
weave_device_id,
where_id,
wiring_error,
wiring_error_timestamp,
y2_type
```

Comment: You need to write a [mcve].